# When switch to new activity, Android softkey board automatically open. I have to close Android softkey board

Tags: android, hidden, android-softkeyboard

When I switch to new activity.the Android soft key board automatically open and I want to disable it. I have tried this code.

```
InputMethodManager inputManager = (InputMethodManager)
                    getSystemService(Context.INPUT_METHOD_SERVICE); 

inputManager.hideSoftInputFromWindow(getCurrentFocus().getWindowToken(),
                       InputMethodManager.HIDE_NOT_ALWAYS);
```

bt didn't work.

Comment: Remove the focus from your second activity's xml file.May be you have provided focus=true in that xml file somewhere.

Answer (score 3):

put this code in your manifest like this

```
 <activity
            android:name="Your Activity name"
             android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden|adjustResize"
             >
        </activity>
```

Let me Know if it helps you

Answer (score 0):

In your AndroidManifest.xml:

```
  <activity android:name="com.your.package.ActivityName"
  android:windowSoftInputMode="stateHidden"  />
```

More [details](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html#wsoft).